# How can I get a list of followers from one instagram account?

Tags: php, api, instagram

I am building a website and all i need is a list of followers from one Instagram account. I've gone through the steps to authenticate my web app with auth 2.0. I just realized that with this authentication I can only access the followers of the account to whom each access token belongs.

Is there any other way that I could access the followers from my desired account?

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/4082347837/followed-by?access_token=AccessToken

Output of API request:-

```
{ ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["error_type"]=> string(18) "APINotAllowedError" ["code"]=> int(400) ["error_message"]=> string(29) "you cannot view this resource" } }
```

Comment: you don't need to be authenticated (i.e. need an `access_token`) to get a list of user followers. You just need your `client_id`. The following request should work in your case: **`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows/?client_id={client_id}`**

Comment: I tried that and I get this error --               {
"meta": {
"error_type": "OAuthParameterException",
"code": 400,
"error_message": "Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."
}
}

Answer (score -1):

Probably, you client_id is in a sandbox mode. You can't get info from accounts except whitelisted. You can leave the sandbox mode if you send you app for the review.

But there is a simplier solution. You can get public info from web version (wihout API) just with one call:

```
$otherPage = 'nasa';
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/$otherPage/?__a=1");
if ($response !== false) {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data !== null) {
        $follows = $data['user']['follows']['count'];
        $followedBy = $data['user']['followed_by']['count'];
        echo $follows . ' and ' . $followedBy;
    }
}
```

**Update.**
Sorry, I've misunderstood your question. It is possible to get the list without API. You need csrf token and user id in cookies, then call the query:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/query/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

//You need the csrftoken, ds_user_id
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: ..."));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$userId = 528817151;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "q=ig_user($userId) {
  followed_by.first(10) {
    count,
    page_info {
      end_cursor,
      has_next_page
    },
    nodes {
      id,
      is_verified,
      followed_by_viewer,
      requested_by_viewer,
      full_name,
      profile_pic_url,
      username
    }
  }
}");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

You can obtain right cookies doing login action on Instagram web.

Comment: this only provides the count and not the list of users