# How to get Instagram image details

Tags: python, json, selenium, instagram

I am working on an app to get images details from Instagram by using selenium with python.

```
driver.execute_script(SCROLL_TOP)
driver.execute_script(SCROLL_BOTTOM)
```

In the result, all posted images and captions can be gotten from `driver.page_source`

But when I trying to get more information about an image (e.g, number of likes, date of the image published). I need to access

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {...}</script>
```

The '...' in the previous code is a JSON block. It contains the first 12 media's details. Is there a way I get all image's details in the window._shareData JSON block?

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836144/php-how-to-get-images-from-instagram-without-api-access-token/40836991#40836991) which solves your problem but with php. Anyway, you can do the same with python:

1. Load the json by http from the url: `https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1` (replace `nasa` with any public username).
2. Get 12 media details from the json: `user->media->nodes`.
3. Get the additional media info from the json: `user->media->page_info`. There are `has_next_page` (boolean) and `end_cursor` (integer). Use it to get next 12 media with url `https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1&max_id=[VALUE-FROM-end_cursor]`.
4. Repeat 2-3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply rNix, it works perfectly. I just wondering where could I find the online document about the ' __a=1' things. I guess there are more parameters I could put into the query to do get data from the Instagram server. Is that right?

Comment: @r0ng I have not seen any. But I found one intersting web endpoint for queries (to get comments, followers, etc). Look at `update` section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648546/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-followers-from-one-instagram-account/40761395#40761395

Comment: @r0ng You can get more examples of queries looking at your browser's console using the web version of Instagram.