# Instagram pagination tag

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I am doing a development based on instagram, I do not use the API because they do not allow applications in development mode but in production mode.

So, I'm trying to get the following pages regarding a hashtag, for example:
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/

The next page is done by sending a POST method, to a /query / and a /ajax/bz, however, trying to try it with cURL does not work for me.

I leave as I have been doing with cURL.

```
curl "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/" --http1.1 -k "https://www.instagram.com/query/" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "q=ig_hashtag(plebiscito)+{+media.after(j0hwe66aaaaaf0hwexjmwaaafkwa,+12)+{++count,++nodes+{++++caption,++++code,++++comments+{++++++count++++},++++comments_disabled,++++date,++++dimensions+{++++++height,++++++width++++},++++display_src,++++id,++++is_video,++++likes+{++++++count++++},++++owner+{++++++id++++},++++thumbnail_src,++++video_views++},++page_info}+}&ref=tags::show&query_id=/" --next --http1.1 -k "https://www.instagram.com/ajax/bz" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"q":[{"page_id":"7mj51x","posts":[["timespent_bit_array",{"tos_id":"7mj51x","start_time":1481556875,"tos_array":[3,0],"tos_len":2,"tos_seq":2,"tos_cum":19,"log_time":1481556876912},1481556876912,0]],"trigger":"timespent_bit_array"}],"ts":1481556877336}' --next -k "https://www.instagram.com/query/" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "q=ig_hashtag(plebiscito)+{+media.after(j0hwe66aaaaaf0hwexjmwaaafkwa,+8)+{++count,++nodes+{++++caption,++++code,++++comments+{++++++count++++},++++comments_disabled,++++date,++++dimensions+{++++++height,++++++width++++},++++display_src,++++id,++++is_video,++++likes+{++++++count++++},++++owner+{++++++id++++},++++thumbnail_src,++++video_views++},++page_info}+}&ref=tags::show&query_id=/" --next -k "https://www.instagram.com/ajax/bz" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"q":[{"page_id":"7mj51x","posts":[["timespent_bit_array",{"tos_id":"7mj51x","start_time":1481556875,"tos_array":[3,0],"tos_len":2,"tos_seq":2,"tos_cum":19,"log_time":1481556876912},1481556876912,0]],"trigger":"timespent_bit_array"}],"ts":1481556877336}'
```

Here I was trying to get page two, however, it responds with a page not found.

In short, I need to automate the pages with Python, but I was testing it with cURL.

Could you help me? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can get a json `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plebiscito/?__a=1` It contains `page_info` with `end_cursor`. Paginate using `max_id=VALUE-FROM-end_cursor` in GET-request. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877566/how-to-get-instagram-image-details/40879609#40879609).

If you want to use `POST /query` you need right cookie.

Comment: Thanks! This works properly, was stalled...So when I'm going to automate the process with Python do I need to put the headers on it?

Comment: What do you mean? Which headers?